# SanDisk Memory Stick Pro Duo isn't detected by Sony notebook

Tags: memory, memorystick

I am trying to transfer images from a SanDisk Memory Stick Pro Duo to my Sony Notebook VGN-N17G. However the memory stick is always undetected by my notebook.

When I tested using a Sony memory stick on the same notebook, everything works well.

How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: The VGN-N17G does not appear on [Sony's Support site](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/hub/NOTEBOOK#VGN-N) can you verify it's correct? Ideally i would link you to a download for the Card reader & chipset for the laptop in question to reinstall/update it. Do you have the original drivers CD?

Comment: Hello Haydn, thanks for the clue. Sony Model PCG-7T2P

Comment: That model number is still not listed on the Sony site, is there one on the large product sticker on the bottom? Also please vote up any answers/comments which are helpful, thanks :)